# How to I get to my linux partition?

Tags: partitioning

So I got a new hard drive. First, I downloaded Ubuntu on to it, because I didn't have windows 7 yet. So a few days later I bought windows 7, and partitioned it on to the hard drive.

Now, when I start the computer, it goes straight to windows 7. That's fine and all, but how do I get to the Ubuntu partition that's somewhere on the hard drive still? I believe it is an extended partition, not a primary.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like when you installed Windows 7 it wrote over the mbr (Master Boot Record) and now it only boots to Windows. You should be able to fix this issue by using this tool: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Basically, your Ubuntu operating system should be intact and working if it wasn't damaged when installing Windows. You just need to repair the mbr so that it knows that Ubuntu is on the computer and will let you boot to it. Ubuntu uses a software called Grub to boot between different operating systems. Using the Boot-Repair program should fix the mbr and set up Grub so that you can boot between Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

Comment: THANKS!! Worked like a charm! http://paste.ubuntu.com/6496353/

Comment: @user220188 If this answer solved your problem, [please accept it](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1141/44179). Thanks :)